# Merging two JSON strings in golang

Tags: json, go

I have a struct which I convert to JSON in the old fashioned way:

```
type Output struct {
    Name     string   `json:"name"`
    Command  string   `json:"command"`
    Status   int      `json:"status"`
    Output   string   `json:"output"`
    Ttl      int      `json:"ttl,omitempty"`
    Source   string   `json:"source,omitempty"`
    Handlers []string `json:"handlers,omitempty"`
  }

sensu_values := &Output{
      Name:     name,
      Command:  command,
      Status:   status,
      Output:   output,
      Ttl:      ttl,
      Source:   source,
      Handlers: [handlers],
    }
```

I want to read an arbitrary JSON file from the filesystem, which can be defined as anything by the user, and then add it to the existing JSON string, taking the duplicates from the original.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you explain more about what you want to do and what you're having trouble with?

Comment: You could read the incoming JSON into a `map[string]interface{}` then iterate that map comparing the keys to field names on the struct and assigning to the struct if there is a match, assuming a type assert on the value succeeds. If the incoming JSON is arbitrary and can include nesting you'll have to use a recursive algorithm to ensure you reach all nested keys.

Comment: So I got as far as reading the incoming JSON into `map[string]interface{}` as you suggest, but then got stuck on the iteration part.

I checked out the mergo library, as well as a bunch of stack overflow answers and such, but coming from a ruby background it all seems a bit more difficult than in ruby :)

Comment: I can give you some guidance in an answer but don't have the time to write hardened code in answer. I would say it's fairly hard logic to implement.

Comment: @Frap when you say arbitrary JSON, can it be anything ? Or would it still have a certain `pattern` ? For example, do you plan to support something like `[{a:1,b:2}]` as well as `{a:1,b:2}`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Input JSON :

```
{
    "environment": "production",
    "runbook": "http://url",
    "message": "there is a problem"
}
```

It's better to unmarshal the input JSON and combine the two structures before marshaling `Output` struct.

Sample Code

```
inputJSON := `{"environment": "production", "runbook":"http://url","message":"there is a problem"}`
out := map[string]interface{}{}
json.Unmarshal([]byte(inputJSON), &out)

out["name"] = sensu_values.Name
out["command"] = sensu_values.Command
out["status"] = sensu_values.Status

outputJSON, _ := json.Marshal(out)
```

[Play Link](https://play.golang.org/p/n_oq89ybA5)

Comment: In terms of requirements, I have an app: https://github.com/jaxxstorm/sensu-wrapper which allows a user to build a JSON string and send it to either a socket or stdout.

The reason I specify arbitrary JSON is because every user has different fields that they might want to send with the monitoring check. If they were fixed fields, I figure it'd be quite easy, but arbitrary JSON and typing seems to be difficult!

Comment: Can you add a sample of an arbitrary input json in the question ? And yes arbitrary JSON can be difficult to handle in Go.

Comment: An example would be: `{"environment": "production", "runbook":"http://url", "message", "there is a problem"}`

Comment: I've updated the answer. Let me know if it cover's your use case.

Comment: Thanks for the update! One question, if I unmarshal the JSON into a struct, I can add each struct value from the original manually, but is there a way to simple merge the two structs and finish with a final struct I can marshal into JSON again?

Comment: No. Since your input JSON is arbitrary, the only option we can use is a `map[string]interface{}` and since you cannot let repeating values in the input JSON overwrite the values defined in `Output`, this is the only way.

Comment: One thing you can do is to skip using `Output` struct and instead directly write the values into the map once it's unmarshaled with with input JSON.

Comment: Excellent, appreciate your help and responses! Have accepted your answer!